# multiple vector manipulations in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

Suppose there have `N` vectors `X_1, X_2, ..., X_N` of length `k` each. We want all possible sums `X_1(i1) + X_2(i2) + ... + X_N(iN)`, where `i1, i2, ..., iN` range from `1...k`. There are `k^N` such sums. Is there any other way of doing it in Matlab using the built in functions, other than having `N for-loops` like below:

```
counter = 1;
for i1=1:k
  for i2=1:k
  .
   .
    .
      for iN=1:k
          res(counter) = X_1(i1) + X_2(i2) + ... + X_N(iN); 
          counter = counter + 1;
      end
    .
   .
  .
  end
end
```

Also, this code needs to be hard-coded for the value of `N`, as we need `N for-loops`. How do we code it for any general value of `N` ?

Answer (score 1):

A single loop of N iterations should be enough. (here it's unrolled)

```
sums=zeros(1,k^N);
id = 1:k^N;
i = mod(id, k)+1; id=(id-i) / k;
sums = sums + X_1(i);
i = mod(id, k)+1; id=(id-i) / k;
sums = sums + X_2(i);
...
i = mod(id, k)+1; id=(id-i) / k;
sums = sums + X_N(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use **ndgrid**.

```
[s{1:N}] = ndgrid(-K:K);
res = zeros(k^N,1);
for i=1:N
   res = res + s{i}(:)
end
```